# How do I read a database while inserting data from another thread?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, sqlite

I am trying to read an sqlite database while I insert data from another thread, but I get locked database error. I tried to create a new instance of the database when I try to read the content but I get the same error. If you have any resources or any idea of how to resolve this issue it will be a great help.

Here is the code I use to initiate the database:

```
- (id)initWithDB:(NSString*)dbName{

    if(self = [super init])
    {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];

            if (sqlite3_open([writableDBPath UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
                    NSLog(@"could not prepare statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
                    NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
            }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Help yourself.  There are more than a thousands topics if you run a search for Objective-C and SQLite here.  There has been nothing new for years.

Comment: Try [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CL I was able to resolve this issue by adding

```
sqlite3_exec(_database, "PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;", 0, 0, 0);
```

after the sqlite3_open() function.